# ASP.NET MVC3 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and Association

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

This part of code works fine

```
[Association(Storage = "profile", ThisKey = "UserId", OtherKey = "UserId")]
public Profile User {
   get { return this.profile.Entity; }
   set { this.profile.Entity = value; }
}
```

but if i add in this class

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

then, Association could not be found.

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enhancement to Austin's answer is to employ the `using` statement:

```
using L2SAssociation = System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association;

[L2SAssociation(Storage = "profile", ThisKey = "UserId", OtherKey = "UserId")]
public Profile User
{
   get { return this.profile.Entity; }
   set { this.profile.Entity = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got two namespaces that are conflicting. Try changing Association to System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association, so it would look like:

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "profile", ThisKey = "UserId", OtherKey = "UserId")]
public Profile User {
   get { return this.profile.Entity; }
   set { this.profile.Entity = value; }
}
```